# What does the term "no slipping" mean in mechanics?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, terminology

Say, I have two blocks. One block is on top of the other. Suppose friction is present everywhere. What is the condition for no slipping?

Comment: The condition of no slipping mean that the relative velocity at the contact point is zero

Answer (score 1):

"No slipping" at a specific surface means the two objects in contact there move as one object because the frictional force developed at that interface is large enough to prevent them from sliding relative to one another.